# What is so offensive about the question, "Why do Democrats want to deny women the right to defend themselves from college rapists?"

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

This question was deleted, with no notice as to why. It seemed perfectly reasonable.

The gist of the question was that Democrats in Colorado want women with Concealed Carry permits to leave their guns off campus.

Please explain the rationale for deleting this question.

Comment: There was notice that the question wasn't suitable for the site, it was closed and there was a brief comment exchange explaining the closure. You may disagree with my reasoning for closing it, but saying that there was no notice is simply not true.

Comment: @YannisRizos, language barrier issue I suppose, but "the question was **deleted**, with no notice as to why." Questions are closed, when they can be improved. Questions are deleted when they are "extremely off-topic" (or rude and offensive to liberals). So, why was the question **deleted** with no notice?

Comment: There's no language barrier issue. The question was closed as "not a real question", it doesn't get more "extremely off topic" on a Q&A site than that.

Comment: @YannisRizos, Thank you for that very specific answer to the question. That was *very* helpful.

Comment: You worded it like a partisan pundit making wild assumptions about intent. You may consider that reasonable, but I don't know that a lot of other people would.

Comment: I'm not able to see your question at the moment, but from what I can gather, your question was `"Here is a news story.  Why did this happen"`.  It's akin to asking on Stack Overflow: `"Here is my code.  Why doesn't it work"`.

Comment: @YannisRizos I also imagine that such a question can be re-phrased, to be appropriate for the site.  If you un-delete the question, I'd be more than happy to edit and re-phrase the question so it's not inflammatory.

Comment: @SamIam The question received offensive flags from the community, and I'm not really eager to undelete it. If you feel there's a good question for the site somewhere in there, I think re-asking it (in a more constructive way) is easier than undeleting and editing the old one.

Comment: I suspect that you are infact a Democrat operative trying to make conservatives look like morons.

Comment: @chad interesting theory! Perhaps we're being elegantly trolled here.

Comment: @SamIam, "Have you noticed **answers** that are backed up with solid references being removed from the site? If so, could you please point me at them, so I can undelete them?" YannisRizos doesn't undelete questions he doesn't like. [Unpopular questions](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/540/can-raising-the-tax-on-the-wealthy-without-cutting-spending-balance-the-federa) have to be worded very carefully so as not to upset the establishment.

Comment: @SamIam, I did mention some of the responses from democrats. One was that the gun might be used against her. I guess they also don't trust women who have been trained (necessary to get the CC permit) to correctly identify when they are in danger. Talk about a war against women.

Comment: @user1873 you don't have to see the content of the question to know that `“Why do Democrats want to deny women the right to defend themselves from college rapists?”` would be extremely inflammatory.  In-fact It looks like a gun-control question, with a story specifically selected to make it as inflammatory as possible

Comment: @SamIam, I suppose since Democrats want to disarm all citizens it would have been possible to ask, "Why do Democrats want to leave citizens defenseless against criminals?" The question was more specific, and focused though (didn't want it closed for being too broad). Democrats were outlawing guns on college campuses, even for those people legally licensed to carry them. The original question posed to the Dems in the hearing didn't receive a satisfactory answer. I was hoping some of the more liberal Dems here could explain how they are safer now?

Comment: @user1873 well, you could have said "why do democrats want to ban guns", and it would be far far less inflammatory, and likely wouldn't have been deleted.

Comment: @user1873 you are using this technique: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_question Whether or not said technique is 'offensive' is up to debate, but it's certainly not a valid way to present a question on SE.

Comment: The problem is all democrats do not want to do anything.  The DNC has as part of its platform improved gun control.  That is not the same as banning all guns no matter how hard the RNC and FNC try to frame it that way.

Comment: @user1873 regarding "trusting women to correctly identify when they are in danger", a lot of the arguments about this have been debunked by the high number of rapes of women in the military.  These are women that are armed, more highly trained than pretty much any college student can be expected to be, and there are still very frequent rapes.  Giving them guns will absolutely not solve the problem, and it makes them more likely (4,500% more likely) to be shot.

Comment: @JNK - women in the military aren't "armed". The military in everyday life is more gun-free than civilian society. See Fort Hood Massacre for the most infamous example.

Comment: @DVK very true for base life.  Less so for active duty.  Regardless, the average female soldier is a lot better equipped to defend herself than the average college student.  And having a gun DOES make an assault victim 4.5x more likely to be shot.

Comment: @JNK - shouldn't it be, like that woman's decison on whether she accepts those odds or prefers to be able to defend herself and not yours?

Comment: @DVK Letting people carry guns affects the safety of more than just those carrying guns.

Comment: @JNK - That's your personal hangup. I'm statistically a lot more worried about people driving cars and large dudes who can (and have) hurt me physically with no guns. I'll trade you prohibition on guns for prohibition on driving cars or for large dudes to walk around unshackled, since we both care about each others safety.

Answer (score 10):

As the moderator who deleted the question, I want to let you in on my reasoning.

1. The point of the question was really to ask about guns.

   I have no problem with essentially asking, "Do guns keep people safe?" ... although, such a question, because of the heat it generates, should be extremely academic in how it is asked.  When I imagine a good answer, I expect:

   - A high ratio of observable and/or reproducable fact to value judgements.
   - An issue that is framed in less partisan terms
   - An answer that does not denigrates those who disagree with it.

   Already, I was finding the question .... lacking.
2. Then, there was the gratuitous use of rape.

   I've counseled women who have been sexually attacked. These are strong women who have been traumatized.  There are times to confront the issue of rape - when that is the issue.  As I said, this was a question about guns.  The rape was there for shock value.

   I have a vested interest in seeing that this site is adopted as widely as possible.  I do not expect a nursery, but I do not expect unnecessary roughness either.  If we are going to ask questions about rape, then let's ask questions rape.  But let's not just throw it in "to make a point."  If you are going to make the site churn up memories for women who have been thus traumatized, I want to see a compelling reason for it.

Taken together, this seemed like troll-bait to me. This was the kind of thing that would needlessly churn up bad feelings without actually advancing the scholarly pursuit of hard facts about our political systems.

It served as a signpost - but one that went in exactly the wrong direction. So, I deleted it.

Comment: Totally wrong. There was a major political discussion started by the Democrats in Colorado legislation precisely on the topic. They claimed that the woman who wanted a gun to protect from rapists didn't have a valid demand. It was a legitimate EXISTING IN REALITY political discussion, not troll bait.

Comment: Political discussions is not what the site is about @DVK. Also, the fact that the discussion is happening in real life doesn't make it less of a troll bait, which is exactly why we need a site like Politics Stack Exchange, where we can _answer questions_ free of the noise, heat and sentimentalism of real life politics.

Comment: @YannisRizos - the point is that if the topic is a subject of a real life discussion, you can't call posting a question aimed at understanding it "troll bait". I really don't see ANY difference (aside from which side looks like an ass) between this question and "why are conservatives anti-science" one which everyone here happily loves because it doesn't paint their favorite side in bad light.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from posting an answer to this Meta question explaining why you think the question in question is a good one for the site @DVK.

Comment: "I really don't see ANY difference" = the difference is that many conservatives and organizations are tied to denying global warming. I'm not aware of any democrats or organizations that are against fighting rape.

Comment: @DA. - if you are trying to fight rape (or any violent crime) by arming yourself with a gun, any gun-rights-denier in effect is against you fighting rape. As a 5'5" guy who was frequently bullied by larger people all his life, I know precisely how valuable a weapon is for self defense.

Comment: @dvk heh. I forgot about this one. user1873 hasn't changed a bit.