# Are links to news articles about gun free zones offensive now?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

YannisRizos asked me to rewrite the question from scratch, removing the partisan retoric. I did so, and asked this question:

**Are you safer in a gun free zone?**

I provided links to the stories in Colorado about law makers making it illegal to carry a weapon on college campus. But, apparently "sneaking in links to related news stories about the question at hand is not allowed."

What in the world could be offensive about a link to a news story?

Comment: At this point, it's not your questions that are offensive. It's your behavior.

Comment: @DA., what specifically about my behavior?

Comment: @DA., "*but Democrats seem to associated with them" = could you please cite more mentions of this out in the wild? As it stands now, it appears you make that association, but I'm not aware of that being a broadly accepted view*" what is funny, is that YannisRizos complains when I link to supporting evidence, and you complain when I don't link to supporting evidence. **Impossible to please everyone**

Comment: What does the question look like now?

Comment: @SamIam, I couldn't tell you YannisRizos is quite quick at deleting entire questions that he doesn't like (instead of just removing the offending "link sharing") instead of closing/editing the question to "community standards." But, I [warned about this](http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/questions/92/are-people-voting-along-political-lines/271#271), you get the community you deserve.

Comment: What part of that discussion do you think meets the criteria for a Constructive question on SE?

Comment: @DA. - yes, I know. Posting true facts that make your political side looks like asses is very offensive.

Comment: @dvk I have no idea what you are referring to.

Comment: He asked you to rewrite "the question". What question? Please try to remember that this is not chat. It's supposed to be a canonical resource about site policy. Without real-time context, this question is completely meaningless.

Comment: @TRiG, [the question](http://www.theblaze.com/stories/2013/02/18/colorado-dem-on-why-women-dont-need-guns-on-campus-you-might-feel-like-youre-gonna-be-raped-but-you-may-actually-not-be/) was about whether women are safer on college campuses without guns than with them. The question was deleted, so I attempted to rephrase the question, but that one was deleted as well (along with the meta ? Asking what was wrong with it). I couldn't give any context to this meta ?, because if I did so I rightfully assumed that it would be deleted (

Comment: other meta questions were previously because they either contained links to give context to the question, or were too politically charged, etc. Don't blame me for lack of context, blame the moderators.

Answer (score 2):

Politics Stack Exchange is not a link sharing site.

The news story may be tangentially related to your question, but the fact that you made a point of linking to it thrice (in the same question) *and* your [past behaviour](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1309/101) on the site made it more than obvious that you were not asking the question in good faith. I've closed and deleted your question, because frankly at this point you are just spamming.